# How to get integration of a function when it is different for different ranges of X?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm stuck on how to solve these continuous random variables, I know how to do it when it is just a simple f(x) like x^2 or X+3 or like that. But this question has two different f(x) for different ranges of x, how to solve this?
[Please can you guys visit the link, I'm not allowed to copy the image directly since my account is new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v59r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Break the integral into pieces depending on its domains of definition.  In your linked example,

$$
\int_{-1}^3 f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_1^2f(x)dx+\int_2^3f(x)dx.
$$
Substituting formulas, you would have
$$
\int_{-1}^00dx+\int_0^1\frac{6}{7}xdx+\int_1^2\frac{6}{7}x(2-x)dx+\int_2^30dx.
$$
After a quick calculus computation, the result is $1$ as expected for a probability distribution.  For your problem, you'll need a different integrand and region of integration.

Comment: Assuming it is a valid density function, this should be $1$. Did you note the exercise is asking for $E(X^2)$?

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes, I noticed $E(X^2)$, but I wanted to leave something for OP.

Comment: Thank you so much !, I understood your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property of integrals:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}x^2f(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)\,dx+\int_{1}^{2}x^2f(x)\,dx+\int_{2}^{\infty}x^2f(x)\,dx$$